# Dropdown list html code

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, django-models

I want to display dropdown choices for certain fields. I have a model workorder and i created a model form. I created a file choices.py and defined the created choices in the model and also at forms.py but I don't know the html code to display the choices. I'm a beginner so would appreciate any help. This is my code: The field I'm trying to make dropdowns is WO_Type_ID.

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField
from MMS.choices import *


class Workorder(models.Model): 
    WO_ID = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    WO_DateDefWO = models.DateField()
    WO_DateSched = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    WO_DateFinished = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    WO_ST_ID_Sign = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    WO_Status_ID = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    WO_Type_ID = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    WO_Comments = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    WO_Nav_ID = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    WO_Nav_Kons_ID = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
    WO_Nav_Name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    WO_Nav_CustAdr = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    WO_Nav_Debt = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    WO_Nav_PropCode = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    WO_Nav_DepCode = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    WO_Nav_PhoneNo = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    WO_Nav_ReasonCompl = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    WO_NightShift = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    WO_Priority = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    WO_RE_ID = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    WO_MapUrl = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.WO_ID
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django import forms
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.http import HttpResponse
from MMS.models import Workorder
from MMS import forms
from MMS.forms import CreateWorkorder
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from . import forms



def workorder_create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateWorkorder(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            CreateWorkorder_item = form.save(commit=False)
            CreateWorkorder_item.save()
            return redirect('/workorder/' + str(CreateWorkorder_item.WO_ID) + '/')
    else:
        form = CreateWorkorder()
    return render(request, 'workorders/workorder_create.html', {'form': form})


def workorder_edit(request, id=None):
    item = get_object_or_404(Workorder, WO_ID=id)
    form = CreateWorkorder(request.POST or None, instance=item)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/workorder/' + str(item.WO_ID) + '/')
    return render(request, 'workorders/workorder_create.html', {'form': form})


def workorder(request, id):
    workorder = Workorder.objects.get(WO_ID=id)
    return render(request, 'workorders/workorder.html', {'workorder': workorder})
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from MMS import models
from MMS.choices import *

class CreateWorkorder(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Workorder
        fields = ['WO_ID', 'WO_DateDefWO', 'WO_Type_ID', 'WO_DateSched', 'WO_Status_ID', 'WO_Nav_ReasonCompl', 'WO_Nav_CustAdr', 'WO_Nav_Name', 'WO_Nav_PhoneNo', 'WO_MapUrl']
        widgets = {
        'WO_ID': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'myfieldclass'}),
        'WO_DateDefWO': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'myfieldclass'}),
        'WO_Type_ID': forms.ChoiceField(choices = TYPE_CHOICES, label="", initial="", widget=forms.Select(), required=True),
        'WO_DateSched': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'myfieldclass'}),
        'WO_Status_ID': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'myfieldclass'}),
        'WO_Nav_ReasonCompl': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'myfieldclass'}),
        'WO_Nav_CustAdr': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'myfieldclass'}),
        'WO_Nav_Name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'myfieldclass'}),
        'WO_Nav_PhoneNo': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'myfieldclass'}),
        'WO_MapUrl': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'myfieldclass'}),
        }
```

workorder_create.html

```
{% extends 'workorders/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<form method="POST" action="">
{% csrf_token %}

<h1> Create Workorder </h1>

{{ form.non_field_errors }}

<div class="field_wrapper">

{{ form.WO_ID.errors }}

<label for="{{ form.WO_ID.id_for_label }}">Id:</label>

{{ form.WO_ID }}

</div>

<div class="field_wrapper">

{{ form.WO_DateDefWO.errors }}

<label for="{{ form.WO_DateDefWO.id_for_label }}">Defined:</label>

{{ form.WO_DateDefWO }}

</div>

<div class="field_wrapper">

{{ form.WO_Type_ID.errors }}

<label for="{{ form.WO_Type_ID.id_for_label }}">Order type:</label>

{{ form.WO_Type_ID }}

</div>

<div class="field_wrapper">

{{ form.WO_DateSched.errors }}

<label for="{{ form.WO_DateSched.id_for_label }}">Date Scheduled:</label>

{{ form.WO_DateSched }}

</div>

<div class="field_wrapper">

{{ form.WO_Status_ID.errors }}

<label for="{{ form.WO_Status_ID.id_for_label }}">Status:</label>

{{ form.WO_Status_ID }}

</div>

<div class="field_wrapper">

{{ form.WO_Nav_ReasonCompl.errors }}

<label for="{{ form.WO_Nav_ReasonCompl.id_for_label }}">Request:</label>

{{ form.WO_Nav_ReasonCompl }}

</div>

<div class="field_wrapper">

{{ form.WO_Nav_CustAdr.errors }}

<label for="{{ form.WO_Nav_CustAdr.id_for_label }}">Address:</label>

{{ form.WO_Nav_CustAdr }}

</div>

<div class="field_wrapper">

{{ form.WO_Nav_Name.errors }}

<label for="{{ form.WO_Nav_Name.id_for_label }}">Customer:</label>

{{ form.WO_Nav_Name }}

</div>

<div class="field_wrapper">

{{ form.WO_Nav_PhoneNo.errors }}

<label for="{{ form.WO_Nav_PhoneNo.id_for_label }}">Tel No:</label>

{{ form.WO_Nav_PhoneNo }}

</div>

<div class="field_wrapper">

{{ form.WO_MapUrl.errors }}

<label for="{{ form.WO_MapUrl.id_for_label }}">Map:</label>

{{ form.WO_MapUrl }}

</div>

<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

choices.py

```
TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('1', ("(-)")),
    ('2', ("Ankesë: Bllokim i Kanalzimit")),
    ('3', ("Ankesë: Ndërprerje e furnizimit të ujit/rënia e presionit")),
    ('4', ("Ankesë: Cilësia e Ujit")),
    ('5', ("Ankesë: Të tjera")),
    ('6', ("Kërkesë : Aplikacion për lidhje të re - pëlqim")),
    ('7', ("Kërkesë : Ndërrim i ujëmatësit")),
    ('8', ("Kërkesë : Rrjedhje e ujit")),
    ('9', ("Kërkesë: Të tjera")),
    ('10', ("Kërkesë : Interne - Intervenim ne ujesjelles")),
    ('11', ("Kërkesë : Interne - Intervenim ne kanalizim")),
    ('12', ("Kërkesë : Interne - Nderrim i ujematesit")),
    ('13', ("Kërkesë : Interne - Bllombim")),
    ('14', ("Kërkesë : Interne - Kyçje/Shkyçje")),
    ('15', ("Orari i caktuar-ujë")),
    ('16', ("Orari i caktuar-kanalizim")),
    ('17', ("Orari per ndërrimin e ujëmatësave"))
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the entire widget parts in forms.py 
Your form should just be :

```
class CreateWorkorder(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = models.Workorder
    fields = ['WO_ID', 'WO_DateDefWO', 'WO_Type_ID', 'WO_DateSched', 'WO_Status_ID', 'WO_Nav_ReasonCompl', 'WO_Nav_CustAdr', 'WO_Nav_Name', 'WO_Nav_PhoneNo', 'WO_MapUrl']
```

Since you have choices specified in models.py, the WO_Type_ID would automatically get rendered as a select tag in html

Comment: The dropdown is appearing but when I enter data for example ('6', ("Kërkesë : Aplikacion për lidhje të re - pëlqim")), I cannot save it. It is saying "Select a valid choice. 6 is not one of the available choices."

Comment: Try removing the redundant brackets in the TYPE_CHOICES
Ex: ('6', "Kërkesë : Aplikacion për lidhje të re - pëlqim").

Remove brackets around "Ker...."

And edit your question to mention this point that you said in the comment